# fwrite function in C

Tags: c

fwrite function is used for writing in binary.

```
fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

here size in "size_t size" represent byte i.e. fwrite() writes nmemb elements of data, each "size" bytes long.

"size" can be 1 byte or can be more. So for int which is of 2 bytes, if we gave 'size' 1 byte,
how that integer is written? May be written integer is wrong? Or we should take care of it while writing integer and set value of size equal to 2?

Comment: If `int` is 2-bytes on your box and you write (`nmemb`) `1-byte` and (`size`) `1-byte` you get the low-byte on little endian boxes and the high-byte on big endian boxes.

Comment: Two-byte ints? Are you on a ZX80? :-)

Answer (score 6):

When you write an `int` array using `fwrite`, you will need to use:

```
size_t num = fwrite(array, sizeof(int), arraySize, file);
if ( num != arraySize )
{
    // Deal with the error condition.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The number of bytes written will be nmemb * size.

But for ints you would write

```
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), number_of_ints, file);
```

(as the size of ints is compiler dependent - usually 4 bytes)

Answer (score 2):

fwrite has a weird interface, but all it does is writes size * nmemb bytes.  You can write (ptr, 1, 4, fp) or (ptr, 4, 1, fp) and you'll get the same output.

if you write (ptr, 1, 1, fp) you'll get the byte at the lowest memory address.  On a little-endian machine, that is the least significant byte of the int.  On a big-endian machine, it's the most significant byte.